Multiplying pyomo variable matrix with a constant matrix
Matrix multiplication of pyomo variable with constant matrix.
I have the pyomo variable defined in the form of matrix, let's say 21x201.
I want to add a constraint that matrix multiplication of pyomo variables such as :
indx = 11 ; A is diagonal matrix containing the number 10 at the diagonal:
x[1:21, 2:indx] = A * x[1:21, 1:10]
How can I achieve this in python and using pyomo model.
Thanking in advance.

what have you treid so far or where are you stuck ?   the docs are here: https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/working_models.html

the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example
